# adding image to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, web, frontend, backend

My code:

```
var a = ["1","2","3"]
console.log(a)
```

> output is [1,2,3]

The expected output is:

> 1.jpg, 2.jpg, and 3.jpg ( all images )

My code is running well in webstorm and giving the expected output. How do I add images? Whenever I try to get an answer for this I'm getting redirected to a new language or framework. How do I add design to my javascript code?

Comment: So are you trying to add the image name or the actual image content to the array?

Comment: If I just output the image name. `console.log(a.map((value)=> {return \`${value}.jpg\`}))`

Comment: I'm trying to add image content. My array is a deck of cards I want to add image to each item, I have the card images ready for each item. I don't know the appropriate way of doing this yet, I'm going to try adding images, then add functions to buttons etc.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to add a postfix to your array, so the code will be:

```
a.map(item => `${item}.jpg`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = ["1", "2", "3"];
const imageFolderPath = "/";
const imageExtension = '.jpg';

var imagePaths = a.map((name) => imageFolderPath + name + imageExtension );

function createImages(imagePaths) {
  return imagePaths.map((imagePath) => {
    const image = document.createElement("img");
    image.setAttribute("src", imagePath);
    return image;
  });
}

function addImagesToDiv(divId, images) {
  const theDiv = document.getElementById(divId);
  images.forEach((image) => theDiv.appendChild(image));
}

const images = createImages(imagePaths);
addImagesToDiv("myDiv", images);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: thank a lot for writing a reply.. I tried this and I got this error : const image = document.createElement("img");
                      ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined

i'm running the code in webstorm IDE

Comment: @PirateHat this code runs on browser. Are you work on browser or nodejs? webstorm is an editor isn't it?

Comment: yes it is.. sorry i forgot to say my results in browser.. it shows empty page.. i tried external .js file and then write in script tag html file.. both shows empty page.

Comment: Yes because in my code I do not know where is your image folder and what iş your image extension

Comment: Add your  some images with img tag manuelly to index.html  file and say to me what are these src values of img tag and i Will help you

Comment: İ make some guess and chane code little bit. Your images are . jpg format and your images and your images are in the same folder.